# Imaginary part of the stress-energy tensor

Tags: vacuum, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, stability, qft-in-curved-spacetime

I just encountered in an article of D. G. Boulware (["Quantum Field Theory in Schwarzschild and Rindler Spaces"](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.11.1404), Phys. Rev. D 11, 1404, 1975, in the last paragraph of the Introduction)
the statement that the imaginary part of matrix elements of the stress-energy tensor in a vacuum (I imagine that this fact generalises to an arbitrary state) is linked to the stability of the vacuum. I guess that a way to see it would be just that some component of the stress-energy tensor is the energy and the eigenvalues of the energy, if imaginary, imply that the state will either be exponentially damped or it will explode (this is just elementary quantum mechanics).

As I was not able to find any discussion about this "imaginary part" looking up on Google, would there be another way to see this stability study of the state than the one I proposed above?